# Is it valid to partially neglect some terms in a higher order contribution?

Tags: taylor-expansion, perturbation-theory

Suppose I have a function $f(x,\alpha)$ which has a convergent expansion in  the small parameter $\alpha$:

$
f(x,\alpha)=\sum_{n=1\dots \infty,i=1\dots k} g(x,n,i)\alpha^n
$

This expansion has $k$ different functions, $g(x,n,i)$  with contribute at any give order $n$.

Now suppose I compute an approximation only taking the first $m$ terms as:

$f_m(x,\alpha) = \sum_{n=1\dots m,i=1\dots10}g(x,n,i)\alpha^n$

Now suppose it is hard to compute the some of the $k$ functions for $g(x,m+1,i)$. Say these functions are for $i=l\dots k$.  I will then try to improve my approximation of $f_m(x,\alpha)$ with the following new approximation:

$
f_{m}'(x,\alpha) = f_m(x,\alpha) + \sum_{i=1}^{l-1}g(x,m+1,i)\alpha^{m+1}
$

Is this approximation necessary better?  Is there any reason it might not be?

More precisely: Define the error: $\Delta_m = \left| f(x,\alpha)-f_m(x,\alpha)\right|$ and $\Delta_m' = \left| f(x,\alpha)-f_{m}'(x,\alpha)\right|$.
Does $\Delta_{m+1}<\Delta_m$ imply $\Delta_{m}'<\Delta_m$.

I am asking this, because often in physics it is attempted to make the order of approximation consistent(i.e computing only approximations of the form $f_m$).  I am now faced with a problem which for which there is a motivation to compute $f_m'$.  I believe it will works well, but I don't want to be clear about the statements I make.  I am also interested in the specific question in it's own right.

Comment: Can this be simplified to saying $f(x)\approx\sum_{m=1}^n\left(\alpha^mg_m(x)+\alpha^mh_m(x)\right)$, where you know $g_i$ up to some index $n$ and $h_i$ up to index $n+1$, then you want to approximate $f(x)$ more closely by taking, $\sum_{m=1}^n\alpha^mg_m(x)+\sum_{m=1}^{n+1}\alpha^mh_m(x)$?

Comment: Ohh, that's a good idea!  You would then have to look at the convergence of $g_m$ and $h_m$.  Would one imply the other? Also for any given approximation method, this separation is arbitrary besides the order your interested in.  This is an interesting way to look at the problem.

Comment: So this definitely can't improve the order of the error, but the question is whether it will decrease the error. I think in general the answer is no because you may have terms in $g_n$ that cancel terms in $h_n$ and hence affect the result when left out. For example if the $O(a^{n+1})$ terms are $5a^{n+1}$ and $-4a^{n+1}$ then their sum is $a^{n+1}$ but if you only consider $5a^{n+1}$ your error is fairly large. If you somehow about the coefficients then you might be able to make a statement but at first glance it doesn't look good in general.